# Unmarshalling Dynamic JSON Data With Overlapping Fields in Golang

Tags: json, go, types, unmarshalling

Sorry If i'm posting a question that has already been answered, but I can't seem to find any similar situations on here. I have a websocket client that receives dynamic json data with overlapping fields. The fact that the fields overlap has has made Unmarshalling very difficult for me.

I have structs for the data types I receive, but I need a way to check the json data before I unmarshal it to a specific struct. I was hoping that an interface could act as a temporary holder and I would then be able to match the interface to the specific struct I want to unmarshal to, but that doesn't seem possible, or I just don't know how to go about it. Here are a few examples of the data types I'm receiving and structs to go along with it in case that helps.

```
response 1: {"connectionID":17973829270596587247,"event":"systemStatus","status":"online","version":"1.9.0"}
response 2: {"channelID":328,"channelName":"ohlc-5","event":"subscriptionStatus","pair":"XBT/USD","status":"subscribed","subscription":{"interval":5,"name":"ohlc"}}
response 3: [328,["1649576721.042916","1649577000.000000","42641.50000","42641.50000","42641.50000","42641.50000","42641.50000","0.00335101",2],"ohlc-5","XBT/USD"]
response 4: {"event":"heartbeat"}

structs below
import (
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
)

type ConnStatus struct {
    ConnectionID        uint64          `json:"connectionID"`
    Event               string          `json:"event"`
    Status              string          `json:"status"`
    Version             string          `json:"version"`
}

type HeartBeat struct {
    Event               string          `json:"event"`
}

type OHLCsuccess struct {
    ChannelID           int             `json:"channelID"`
    ChannelName         string          `json:"channelName"`
    Event               string          `json:"event"`
    Pair                string          `json:"pair"`
    Status              string          `json:"status"`
    Subscription        OHLC            `json:"subscription"`
}

type OHLC struct {
    Interval        int         `json:"interval"`
    Name            string      `json:"name"`
}

type OHLCUpdates struct {
    ChannelID           int
    OHLCArray           OHLCNewTrade
    ChannelName         string
    Pair                string
}

type OHLCNewTrade struct {
    StartTime           UnixTime
    EndTime             UnixTime
    Open                float64
    High                float64
    Low                 float64
    Close               float64
    VWAP                float64
    Volume              float64
    Count               int
}

type UnixTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (u *UnixTime) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    var ts int64
    err := json.Unmarshal(d, &ts)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    u.Time = time.Unix(ts, 0).UTC()
    return nil
}
```

Any idea(s) on how to go about this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I want to subscribe to more endpoints that will probably give me a few different response types, but this is it for now, at least

Comment: Unfortunately, that's correct. They're all through one websocket connection and there's no header to give an idea of the response that is being sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you in control of the different responses? If so, wow about adding a "type" field to the top level?

See "How to put everything at the top level" section on https://eagain.net/articles/go-dynamic-json/ for more info.

E.g. (untested):

```golang
func UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    var jsonValue map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(d, &jsonValue)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    switch jsonValue["type"] {
    case 1:
        // unmarshal into struct type 1
    case 2:
        // unmarshal into struct type 2
    default:
        // throw err
    }

    // or if you don't have access to type:
    if jsonValue["connectionID"] != nil {
        // unmarshal into struct type 1
    }

    return nil
}
```

Alternatively you could try to (strictly) unmarshal into each struct, until you don't get an error, e.g. something like:

```golang
func DetermineStruct(d []byte) int {
    var connStatus *ConnStatus

    reader := bytes.NewReader(d)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(reader)
    decoder.DisallowUnknownFields()

    err := decoder.Decode(connStatus)
    if err == nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(d, &connStatus)
    if err == nil {
        return 1
    }

    var ohlcSuccess OHLCsuccess
    err = json.Unmarshal(d, &ohlcSuccess)
    if err == nil {
        return 2
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not in control of the responses, so sadly i don't think it's possible to have a type added to them. i was thinking i could try the error checking route, but it didn't seem to work since the responses have overlapping fields and won't throw an error. is there a way to unmarshal to a temporary data holder and then maybe check which keys exist in that holder and go from there?

Comment: @Grant ah right, I think you need the `DisallowUnknownFields` in a json decoder. I've updated the 2nd part of the answer to include this. The 1st answer should allow you to check for arbitrary keys too

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your response until now. Thank you so much for the follow up! I'll be trying this out tomorrow and I'll let you know how it works out. At first glance, this looks super promising though! I was wondering where the reader variable come from, though? Is it part of the io package? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ah, I've now added a line to show you how to get the reader variable from the bytes you already have

Comment: Thank you so much! Where does the api.CCRecipient{} come from as well?

Comment: Ah apologies, that wasn't meant to be included. I've updated the answer now

Comment: Great! This works pretty well for me. It's still not perfect but it's much better. Thank you so much for everything

Sadly if there are fields in your struct that aren't in the json response, it'll still decode, but as long as you're smart about what order the responses are decoded, it works!